# Les actes que nous avons commis pour nous affirmer viennent du même coup (de) nous enchainer

Tags: prépositions, verbes

*Le manuscrit* de Marc Desrochers :

> Nous réalisons de plus en plus que les actes que nous avons commis
> pour nous affirmer **viennent** du même coup (de) nous enchainer aux
> personnes que nous avons rejetées.

Après *viennent*, il ne faudrait-il pas mettre un "de" ? Comme dans *je viens d'arriver* ?

Answer (score 3):

« Venir de + infinitif » et « venir + infinitif » n’expriment pas la même notion.
Le premier exprime le passé proche.
Le deuxième permet de renforcer l’idée exprimée par le verbe.

Comment: Merci. _Le deuxième permet de renforcer l’idée exprimée par le verbe._ --- Pourriez-vous préciser svp ? Ou donner un exemple ?

Comment: "Venir+ infinitif" (sans *de* ) peut parler aussi du commencement de l'action exprimEe par le verbe, **je crois** . Si c'est le cas, peut-etre "... viennent ... nous enchainer aux ..." veut dire "commencent a nous enchainer aux ..." (are beginning to chain us to ...).

Comment: On pourrait écrire la phrase sans le verbe venir : les actes nous enchaînent… Le fait d’ajouter le verbe venir permet de mettre en relief le verbe enchaîner.

Answer (score 0):

*Du même coup* est une locution adverbiale, similaire à *par la même occasion*, *en même temps* ou *simultanément*.

On peut la supprimer sans que la grammaticalité de la phrase en soit affectée :

> [...] les actes que nous avons commis pour nous affirmer **viennent nous enchaîner** aux personnes que nous avons rejetées.

On a ici affaire à un présent alors que l'ajout de la préposition *de* changerait le sens de la phrase :

> [...] **viennent de nous enchaîner** [...]

Ici, il s'agirait d'un passé récent, *venir* faisant alors office de semi-auxiliaire.

Comment: C'est vrai, merci. Je pense que j'aurais dû écrire _C'est une perte **de** temps_ et non _du_, mais je ne peux plus corriger.

Comment: Oui, je n'avais même pas remarqué et avais lu *perte de temps*.

Comment: De la même façon, mon cerveau omet souvent les articles. Je dois me concentrer, lire plus lentement pour les "voir".